# How do I get an item's language versions in GraphQL?

Tags: jss, graphql

I'm using a GraphQL query that at its most basic looks like this:

```
{
  item(path: "/sitecore/content/Home", language: "en") {
    name
    languages {
      name
      version
      language {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have two languages configured under `/sitecore/system/Languages`, `en` and `es`, however, the item only has an `en` version and no `es` version. Language fallback is not enabled.

When executing this query, instead of only getting the `en` version, I get both languages back, like so:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "item": {
      "name": "Home",
      "languages": [
        {
          "name": "Home",
          "version": 1,
          "language": {
            "name": "en"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Home",
          "version": 1,
          "language": {
            "name": "es"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a good way to either:

- correctly return only the languages that have actual versions?
- or, return some kind of flag along with the version item so it can be filtered out at consumption?

Comment: Hi @George Chang,

I have tried the same query in my EDGE, but im getting only EN Version alone, not the other language version which i have not created.
But if I created and published the other language version to the EDGE then i can able to get both language item details.
But once i removed that other language item and published to EDGE , now getting only getting EN item.
I guess es version item might be already in EDGE, mine also language fallback not enabled, for now i couldn't reproduce this issue. i will try to find and provide more info.

Comment: Query only returns the language you have configured on item.